# How to get info of clicked Hyperlink from HTML page over Browser in ios

Tags: ios, httpserver

I want to start downloading the content after clicking Hyperlink but before doing this , i need to distinguish the hyperlink info. When I click Hyperlink , I got the following data :

GET /File1 HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.X.X:8080

User-Agent: xxxxx

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Referer: http://192.168.X.X:8080/

Connection: keep-alive

File1 is hyperlink So any body can suggest me , how can I identify hyperlink ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be assuming your server receives the following get request.

```
GET /File1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.84:8080
User-Agent: Midori (because why not)
Accept: text/html,*/*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

After identifying the HTTP request and the HTTP version, you can then proceed to identifying the requested resource, which in this case is "/File1". Once you've identified it, you can then proceed to handling the GET request. In other words: either reply an error code or a status message with the entity-body of the response containing "File1".

This means that your hyperlink is referencing: href="File1"

The href field in the HTML tag defines what the browser is going to request between the "GET" part and the "HTTP/1.1" part of the request.